# SSMS2012 does not show non-index predicates on index seek?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-execution-plan, ssms-2012

Although SSMS2012 execution plan does show me all the seek predicates of a non-clustered index seek operation, it does not show any other predicates:

[image]

However, if I save the execution plan as XML file, I can see other predicates:

```
<SeekPreidcates>
    ...
</SeekPredicates>
<Predicate>
    <!-- some ScalarOperator elements, reflecting the WHERE clauses which are not directly hit by the index -->
</Predicate>
```

Is this a bug? Does anybody know why SSMS is hiding them?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. `SELECT * FROM master..spt_values WHERE type = 'P' AND high = 128` shows the residual predicate in the tooltip on both 2008 and 2012 for me. [SSMS 2012 version](http://i.stack.imgur.com/EjDsQ.png) Please supply a full XML that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Uhm, interesting. At first your query yielded nothing as well, however, after restarting SSMS it shows the predicates... maybe a bug... thank you!